# How to securely store code from input

Tags: php, html, security

I am currently building an administration panel. There is a page where a file containing HTML is loaded into a html editor (TinyMCE) and is saved to the same file that was loaded (to save the changes).

The file is simply a page that has dynamic links that are to be interchanged from an administration panel. If all of these pages were the same, then I would simply save core values to a database and then load specific sections, however that is not the case as there are many variations of the templates, it's rare that any two are the same.

Therefore, I wanted an application that clients could use to edit these pages themselves. How would I go about saving these files in a secure way that strips any malicious behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't. Store them in the db as is, they can't do any harm there. Make sure they are properly filtered on the out when rendering to the page with `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: It's better to store the original and then filter upon output so that when newer versions of HTML come out (*etc. etc.*) you only need to update the output filters rather than tit about actually editing the database contents. It's far easier to keep it all up to date and secure.

Comment: @Martin In that scenario, what would happen about them adding images and other HTML tags via TinyMCE? As I understand you, you're talking about storing plain-text values only, right?

Comment: If you don't want them to store images then you should use strip_tags(allowable tags) eg `strip_tags('<p><h1>')`, again do this on the way out of the db not the way in, fixing your output code is trivial, fixing incorrectly stored data however.....

Comment: Jarrod, I mean do not strip out code upon *inserting* data into the database, only upon when the data is output *from* the database. For example, you may strip out `<script>` tags because of their obvious risk, but if in the future (well, now) you can make `<script>` tags safe via using [Content Security Policy](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) and script tags are useful to the end user, it's a loss to remove them on input better to remove them on output and then when you have a working Content Security Policy for the site, you can seemlessly use them

Comment: If you remove them on input you'd then need to engage with all your users and say `"hey, you can now keep all the scripts you tried to save before"`. And each user would need to mess about adding code that they had originally added, to their data.

Comment: It should also be noted at this point that you really MUST use Prepared Statements to access the DB when dealing with code blocks, and use regex as much as you can, it's far more powerful than PHPs default string functions.

Comment: @Martin andrew, Understood. I will have to make some changes, it's clear. In regards to your last comment though Martin, I'm actually using Laravel so there shouldn't be too many problems there. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanitising html when storing it in  the db is generally a bad idea, if you get it wrong and you corrupt the data there is no going back, you'd have to get your users to re-input the content once you'd fixed any mistakes. You might think you've covered all bases but there will always be that user that says "When I do this...."

Instead just store the data in the database as it comes in (obviously filtering for sql injection) You don't want Mr O'reilly breaking your db.

You need to filter the content on the way out of the db, how you do this depends on your circumstances.

If you are just expecting your users to store text, then using `htmlspecialchars` is sufficient this will change `<` to `&lt;` and so on

However if you want your users to be able to use tags then strip tags would be more appropriate

eg

```
$allowable_tags = array(
  '<p>',
  '<h1>',
  '<h2>',
  '<h3>',
  '<strong>',
  '<em>',
);


$content =  $db->get($page_id);

echo strip_tags($content,implode('',$allowable_tags));
```

Comment: While this is a good answer,  It is worth noting that `strip_tags` is only part of the solution, as `strip_tags` does not check for attributes inside any allowed tag. OP should use a comprehensive regex system to check things such as script attributes like `onclick=''` from within allowed tags. 
I also very highly recommend OP uses **Content Security Policy** to further secure their (and their clients) code.